# determining a path using recursion

Tags: c

I am trying to find the shortest path in a maze, so far I can print this

```
##########00######00##########
##++04++02++##++##++02++04++##
##06######02##14##########06##
##++##++04++##++12++10++08++##
##08++06##################08##
######++##++14++14++12++10++##
##12##08##12##################
##++10++10++##--------------##
##12##########--##########--##
##++14++16++##--------------##
##########18##################
```

The numbers represent the cost amounted throughout a path. There are multiple paths in this maze from the entry point at the top, which crossover a lot as seen in the maze. I am looking to find the shortest path, which would look something like this:

```
##########00######  ##########
##        ..##  ##          ##
##  ######02##  ##########  ##
##  ##..04..##              ##
##    06##################  ##
######..##                  ##
##  ##08##  ##################
##..10..    ##--------------##
##12##########--##########--##
##..14..16..##--------------##
##########18##################
```

I used recursion to find these costs, and I'm just looking for suggestions as to how I can achieve this. The cost values are stored in my program, so I just want to find a method to solve the shortest path in the maze.

Is there a way where I can tweak this function to also find the shortest path?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Once you have an array with all of the distances, start from the end (18) and work back to the beginning. For example, when you reach the 11, you have a choice between 12 and 10, so choose 10.

Comment: @RoadRunner You've posted many maze questions in the last few days, many of which have been closed as too broad (and one which was a near dupe of this). It seems like you're generating your homework code one stack-overflow answer at a time.

Comment: Well, just to let you know sir, everything that has been written into my code has been my own work. I may ask alot of questions about it, but I do not take code of this site and submit it as my own. If I have a problem with something, I will ask questions, that's just what I do. A lot of them might be put on hold but I am trying to get answers that will point me in the right direction. 

To all the kind,  helpful people that have got me in the right direction, I will post my solution later just to show people like you that everything I put into that code is my own work.

Comment: Not once did you offer any sort of help or advice for my questions @Paul Hankin. Nothing constructive at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some comments on your current code:

#### Type of `reachable` property

```
maze->MAZE[row][col].reachable = "+";
```

This suggests that `reachable` is a string, but that is a bit overkill. Define it as a `char`, and write:

```
maze->MAZE[row][col].reachable = '+';
```

#### Entry point is also an exit

In the example maze, you set the start point at `(0, 5)`, but if the goal is to find the shortest path to exit the maze, then of course it is only one step away: go up, and you're out. This was surely not what you intended, and so for the algorithm to give the correct shortest path, you need to close that exit. I would suggest to work with this modified example maze, where the starting point would be moved to `(1, 5)`. I marked it with an `*`:

```
    #########.#####
    #....*#.#.....#
    #.###.#.#####.#
    #.#...#.......#
    #...#########.#
    ###.#.........#
    #.#.#.#########
    #.....#.......#
    #.#####.#####.#
    #.....#.......#
    #####.#########
```

Now there is no such short-cut exit any more.

#### Unnecessary `if` conditions

The four conditions on `reachable` are unnecessary:

As you have just set the `reachable` property to `+`, the `if` statements that follow will will always be satisfied, so these conditions are not needed.

Also the second condition that has this:

```
maze->MAZE[row][col].type != '.'
```

... is not necessary, as you already exit the function when it is true the first time. So the second `if` can do without this.

#### Put recursive call in loop

Instead of repeating the recursive call four times in your code, you could put that in a `for` loop, making use of an array that gives the direction to go:

```
int dir, direction[] = {0, -1, 0, 1, 0};
// ...
for (dir = 0; dir < 4; dir++) {
    traverse(maze, row + direction[dir], col + direction[dir+1], cost + 1);
}
```

#### What to add to get shortest path

Now based on the above adjusted code, you could calculate an inverse cost, i.e. the shortest distance to the exit. This you could return as value of the `traverse` function. On top of that, you could store the direction to take at each cell as a value between 0 and 3. I have called this new property `shortest_path_direction`:

The function `traverse` would then look like this:

```
int direction[] = {0, -1, 0, 1, 0};

int traverse(maze_t * maze, int row, int col, int cost) {
    int dir, dist, best_dist = 1000000; // represents "infinity"

    if ( row < 0 || row >= maze->rows || col < 0 || col >= maze->columns ) {
        return 0; // distance from exit is 0.
    }
    // If row,col is not open
    if (maze->MAZE[row][col].type != '.') {
        return best_dist; // not possible, distance is infinite 
    }
    // Compare costs of different paths
    if (maze->MAZE[row][col].min_cost < cost) {
        return best_dist; // not shortest path, distance is infinite
    }
    maze->MAZE[row][col].min_cost = cost;
    // Mark row,col as part of path.
    maze->MAZE[row][col].reachable = '+'; // use char type
    // Search neighboring cells
    for (dir = 0; dir < 4; dir++) {
        dist = traverse(maze, row + direction[dir], col + direction[dir+1], 
                              cost + 1);
        if (dist < best_dist) {
            best_dist = dist;
            maze->MAZE[row][col].shortest_path_direction = dir;
        }
    }
    return best_dist+1;
}
```

You can see that code run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/575129), where I have added a function that loads a maze from a string, and one that prints the shortest path as a series of coordinates, based on the new property `shortest_path_direction`.

#### Performance

It was not your question, but you should be aware that the search you do is not optimal. In the sample maze, you first find the path that goes like this:

```
    ######### #####
    #.....# #     #
    #.### # ##### #
    #.#   #       #
    #...######### #
    ###.#         #
    # #.# #########
    #...  #       #
    #.##### ##### #
    #.....#       #
    #####.#########
```

And then another path is followed:

```
    ######### #####
    #    .# #     #
    # ###.# ##### #
    # #...#       #
    #  .######### #
    ###.#         #
    # #.# #########
    #...  #       #
    #.##### ##### #
    #.....#       #
    #####.#########
```

It is a waste of time that most of that path was already visited (including all branches that were not optimal) before. An efficient algorithm will not go through a whole branch a second time.

Although that can be improved, you should probably have a look at a breadth-first search instead.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way where I can tweak this function to also find the shortest path?

Yes.  Update the `maze_t` struct to have a member pointing to a predecessor.  Whenever `traverse()` updates a node's `min_cost`, have it also set that node's predecessor to the one from which the node is reachable at that cost.  When the function is done, you can trace a minimum-length path backwards from exit to entrance through the chain of predecessors.  (There can be more than one min-length path; this approach gets you exactly one of them.)

Do note, however, that one would ordinarily use Dijkstra's algorithm or a similar best-first search algorithm for shortest path determinations.  *Update: since every step in every path has the same incremental cost, the plain breadth-first search that @TomKarzes suggests serves as a best-first search as well.*  Your depth-first approach is pretty inefficient in comparison.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking of having a "visited" member in the struct. So I'm trying to understand your second sentence. Is this the idea you mean:
maze->MAZE[row[[col].visited = maze->MAZE[row][col].reachable?
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't think this works.  Suppose you're trying to reach node G, and you first find it through an immediate predecessor P.  If P has cost 10, then G has cost 11 and G's predecessor is P.  Now suppose we reach G through another predecessor R and R has cost 9.  We update G's predecessor to R and G now has cost 10.  Finally, suppose we find another path to P through P's predecessor Q, and Q has cost 5.  So P's predecessor is updated to Q and P now has cost 6.  But here it stops, which is not correct.  It needs to revisit G to set G's predecessor back to P and update G's cost to 7.

Comment: How would you go about this instead @Tom Karzes?

Comment: @RoadRunner The way I've always done this is to do a simple breadth-first search using a queue.  Remove the oldest entry from the queue, visit its immediate successors, and add them to the queue if they have not been visited before.  Repeat until the queue is empty.

Comment: Yeah I've never done a breadth-first search using a queue. I was hoping that I could use my recursive function to do this.

Comment: @RoadRunner I don't think you can solve this efficiently using recursion, at least not without making some fairly strong assumptions (i.e., 2D, start at an edge, end at an edge).  The queue solution is very simple though.  You just need to implement a very basic queue to achieve it.  Let me know if you want more detail.

Comment: Update:  This solution absolutely does *not* work.  Here's a stronger counter-example:  You find a path from S to A of length 10, and from A to B of length 10.  So S to B is 20, and A is marked as having cost 10 and B is marked as having cost 20.  You then find a new path from S to A of length 4, so A is marked as having cost 4, but B is still marked as having cost 20.  You then find a new path of length 16 from S to B, so B's predecessor is changed and its cost if marked as 16.  But the best path is S->A->B (4+10 = 14).  So this algorithm is broken and I believe unfixable.

Comment: @TomKarzes, this solution *does* work, on account of the OP's algorithm being so inefficient.  Take your second example.  After the length-4 path from S to A is discovered, the algorithm re-traces all the possible paths from A to other nodes, updating their costs (and possibly their predecessors) as it goes.  Or to put it another way, as long as the OP's algorithm works to find the length of the minimum path -- which I think it does -- the approach I describe serves to discover a path of that length.

Comment: @TomKarzes, in fact, this strategy for finding a path with minimal length works also works in conjunction with Dijkstra's algorithm or the plain breadth-first search you suggest.

Comment: If the original algorithm does what you say it does, then it runs in exponential time rather than linear time, which is unacceptable.  It's a bug.  Adding code on top of that which relies on that bug for correctness makes no sense.  With a breadth-first soluition, you don't need to compare path lengths because the very first time you visit a node, you have found the shortest path and it never needs to change, due to constant-weight edges.

Comment: @TomKarzes, yes, the original algorithm runs in exponential time.  No, this is not efficient.  Yes, I already commented on the algorithm's inefficiency in my answer.  No, the question is not actually about that: it is about how to modify the given algorithm so that it provides not just the minimum path length, but also the path.  Yes, my answer explains that.